# Wacom Inkspace: Is it possible to use Inkspace with intuos4?

Tags: wacom

Is it possible to use Wacom's inkspace with intuos4? If so, can you use the default pen or do you need anything different for it to be compatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inkspace is supposed to be a cloud service that sync from the Bamboo Paper app. Since the app is available to Appstore (iPad, iPhone & iPod Touch), Google Play Store & Windows Store only. You can not use Intuos 4 on these devices.

However if you could find some hardware (connector etc) to connect your intuos to these devices, chances are you could use Bamboo paper with your intuos 4 that will sync your notes to Inkspace.